# Why is my while loop spitting out the same row 50+ times? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my code:

```
public function GetLatestUsers(){
    $statement = $this->Db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 10");
    $statement->execute();
            
    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

And here is the while loop:

```
<?php  
    
    while($row = $crud->GetLatestUsers()){     
?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="" style="border-radius:15px; margin-right:10px;" width="25px" height="25px">  <?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
            <td><font color="green">Positive</font></td>
            <td>Confirmed</td>
            <td><a href="">Feedback</a></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }    
?>
```

This is just returning 50+ of the same row, aka the only row in the database, but it should only return it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running the query again in each loop.

```
$result = $crud->GetLatestUsers();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
// do whatever.
}
```

GetLatestUsers should return the statement.

```
return $statement;
```

Comment: But now it returns nothing? :D

Comment: You have something wrong. If you're returning the statement and that query returns data, it should loop through them in the while loop.

Comment: @Halfstop the GetLatestUsers method fetches one row and returns it. `$result` will be an array.

Comment: @Don'tPanic the query returns 10 and I said return the statement in that function rather than the result of a fetch on a statement.

Comment: And since the original example mingles html and php, there's no reason to have the GetLatestUsers function, just run the query and loop the results. Abstracting out that sql statement seems pointless, but I don't know anything about the larger application.

Comment: Oops, somehow I completely overlooked the part where you told them to `return $statement`.

Comment: same, and me too

Comment: Halfstop - Thanks for the help and no you are correct, but i am practicing :)

Comment: @MichaelJørgensen great. we all started where you are at one point. Can you mark the answer as the correct one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the query and returning one row from the function and the `while` loop is running this infinitely (probably until maximum execution time is expired).  Better would be to return all rows as an array:

```
$statement = $this->Db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 10")
$statement->execute();
return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then loop the return of the function:

```
foreach($crud->GetLatestUsers() as $row){
    // do stuff with $row
}
```